# Android Tv power status monitor using HDMI CEC

Tags: java, android, android-tv

I am working on a Android Tv app which uses HDMI CEC to control devices, in which I want to pass a parameter to Db when TV power status is "ON". How can I monitor power status of Android TV. Should I go for a broadcast receiver to monitor the changes in background? If yes, what base should I use to monitor. I can't go for `Battery_state` since TV will not have battery!

I am using a RF remote that connects to the BOX. Can I control volume control from android which should be in charge of TV volume?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!